# Delete part of UILabel Programmatically - Xcode

Tags: ios, cocoa, uilabel

I have a UILabel which displays a bit of data downloaded from a JSON feed which displays the day of the week (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday).

I was wandering if there is a way to programmatically tell Xcode to shorten the UILabel to 3 letters?

I know there are other ways of achieving what I want, for example a simple set of if functions can do the job, but I don't want to actually read the label and then replace it, I just want to shorten the label.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why don't you just adjust the width of the UILabel frame?

Comment: I guess I could.... but I would be interested if what I want to do is possible.

Comment: That wouldn't work. A width that would display 3 "M" characters would display maybe 5 or 6 "l" characters. And anyway you'd have to choose between possibly clipping letters in half, and using an ellipsis.

Comment: Or calculate it depending on the string and font maybe.. But it wouldn't be pretty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont see a way with stock UILabels BUT it d be easy subclass UILabel and override setText or text.

Something like

```
@interface MyLabel : UILabel
@property(assign) NSUInteger maxLength;
@end

@implementation MyLabel 
- (void)setText:(NSString*)s {
    [super setText:[s substringToIndex:self.maxLength]];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

In `swift 4.2` you can use this custom class:

```
import UIKit

class LabelWithMaxLength: UILabel {
    var maxLength: Int = 3

    override var text: String? {
        get {
            return super.text
        }
        set(s) {
            super.text = (s as NSString?)?.substring(to: maxLength)
        }
    }
}
```

Set the label custom class to `LabelWithMaxLength` in the Interface builder:

[image]

Then in your code just use it like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var dayOfWeekLabel: LabelWithMaxLength!

dayOfWeekLabel.text = "Sunday" //or whatever was the text
```

The result will always generate 3-length character label :)

Answer (score -2):

```
UILabel *label=[UILabel alloc]init];   //label object

//Assume you will be having label text in labelText NSString object.

label.text=[labelText substringToIndex:3];
```

Comment: OP "I don't want to actually read the label and then replace it, I just want to shorten the label."